# Spring Boot is not loading CSS and JS files properly

Tags: javascript, css, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

When I use `@GetMapping("/index")` CSS and JavaScript files load properly.

But when I use `@GetMapping("/admin/index")` CSS and JavaScript files don't load properly.

Works fine for

```
@GetMapping("/index")
public String indexPage()
{
    return "index";
}
```

Not working for

```
@GetMapping("/admin/index")
public String indexPage()
{
    return "index";
}
```

Project structure is

[image]

JSP Page

[image]

Comment: Please share the 404 error you see in the BROWSER console.

Comment: bootstrap.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: problem occurs while using @GetMapping("/admin/index"). Works fine while using @GetMapping("/index")

Comment: could you post your ressource mapping here ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS and CSS files are requested from the browser relatively to the current location. That means that if you are:

- on the URL http://server/yourapp/index, the requested bootstrap css (for example) is http://server/yourapp/vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
- on the URL http://server/yourapp/admin/index, the requested bootstrap css (for example) is http://server/yourapp/admin/vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

If you want to use your second mapping @GetMapping("/admin/index"), you should request your JS and CSS differently in the JSP